# Blockchain Python Syntax Error (Snakecoin)

Tags: python, syntax-error, blockchain

I seem to be having an error in my code. A syntax error, to be specific. I don't know how to to fix it, and the red highlight is over a quotation mark. If the answer is easy, then I am sorry, because I'm not the greatest at Python or coding in general.

```
import hashlib as hasher
import datetime as date

class Block:
  def __init__(self, index, timestamp, data, previous_hash):
    self.index = index
    self.timestamp = timestamp
    self.data = data
    self.previous_hash = previous_hash
    self.hash = self.hash_block()

  def hash_block(self):
    sha = hasher.sha256()
    sha.update(str(self.index) + 
               str(self.timestamp) + 
               str(self.data) + 
               str(self.previous_hash))
    return sha.hexdigest()

def create_genesis_block():
  return Block(0, date.datetime.now(), "Genesis Block", "0")

def next_block(last_block):
  this_index = last_block.index + 1
  this_timestamp = date.datetime.now()
  this_data = "Hey! I'm block " + str(this_index)
  this_hash = last_block.hash
  return Block(this_index, this_timestamp, this_data, this_hash)

blockchain = [create_genesis_block()]
previous_block = blockchain[0]

num_of_blocks_to_add = 20

for i in range(0, num_of_blocks_to_add):
  block_to_add = next_block(previous_block)
  blockchain.append(block_to_add)
  previous_block = block_to_add
  print 'Block #{} has been added to the blockchain!'.format(block_to_add.index)
  print "Hash: {}\n".format(block_to_add.hash)
```

The error is in this line, the red highlight over the end quotation mark:

```
  print 'Block #{} has been added to the blockchain!'.format(block_to_add.index)
```

I got this directly off of [this](https://medium.com/crypto-currently/lets-build-the-tiniest-blockchain-e70965a248b) website.
(If this was formatted wrong then please excuse me, I'm new to this website.)

Comment: Report the error you get. Remove your "Please Help". It actually minimizes your chances of getting an answer. Also, if any answer does what you want, please consider ticking it as correct. A reputation of 1 is enough to do it. I remind you this because newcomers often forget to do so. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) That being said, welcome on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Python 2.7 or higher, you should use print as a function. 
Here is example usage:

```
print('Block #{} has been added to the blockchain!'.format(block_to_add.index))
```

Comment: Parentheses in Python 2.7.+ are not required actually.

Comment: There's no `from __future__ import print_function` in the OP's code, so this could not possibly solve the problem"

Answer (score 0):

Change the line to:

```
print('Block #%s has been added .... blockchain' %(block_to_add.index))
```

and it will work.
You will get the same error for the next print line as well. So change accordingly throughout your code.